# Keyerror after concatenating two series from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this -

```
            Open   High    Low  Close  Volume  Open Interest
  9/1/94   97.86  98.29  97.64  97.76   39772          89054
  9/2/94   97.77  97.84  97.59  97.81   26715          84291
  9/6/94   97.61  97.97  97.40  97.91   37577          86687
  9/7/94   97.93  98.12  97.90  98.10   33530          81909
  9/8/94   98.08  98.24  97.85  97.96   43041          79094
  9/9/94   97.93  98.18  97.80  97.82   50432          70912
  9/12/94  97.74  97.89  97.64  97.68   33660          60634
```

which I get by doing the following

```
    NQ = pd.read_csv('NQ.csv',index_col=0)
    NQ.index.name = None
```

I then extract just the rows and the close column, using this code

```
NQ_data = pd.DataFrame(NQ.loc['9/1/94','1/10/20', 'Close'])
```

Then I rename the column name using pd.rename like so

```
NQ_data = NQ_data.rename(columns = {'Close': 'NQ'})
```

All good so far. Now I do the same as above with another data set to extract the 'Close' column and dates (both datasets have the same set of date indices).

I use pd.concat to merge them like so -

```
ES_and_NQ = pd.concat([ES_data, NQ_data], axis = 1, join = 'outer')
```

But after doing so, I can no longer access data in this new column using the date. For instance

```
ES_and_NQ['9/1/94']
```

throws up a key error, even though when I look at ES_and_NQ.index, this date is listed there. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you mean to do: `ES_and_NQ.loc['9/1/94']`?

Comment: Wow, that was it......but now I'm confused - don't we have to use loc when we specify both axes? Shouldn't the way I have it still give us the row?

Comment: We use .loc or iloc to access by rows, and brackets for columns.

Comment: You can also use both axes with .loc or .iloc, but you don't have to.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy coding to you.